# How to get the environment at execution for FastReport

Tags: fastreport

We are using FastReport with our on-premise ERP software.
Reports are designed with the FastReport Desktop (version 2021.4.15).
The reports are executed from within the ERP client which runs in the browser.
As we have multiple instances of the ERP (Dev, Test, Training, Production, ...) we need to include the environment in which a report is being executed.

I have looked at using the Report or Engine classes but I can't find any property or method that could give me a hint: I would be happy if I could retrieve the URL or server name or just anything that could help in distinguishing the environment.